# kubernetes mariadb galera replication across cluster

Tags: kubernetes, mariadb, database-replication, galera

**The requirement is to do mariadb replication across two kubernetes cluster**

I have one k8s cluster and each cluster running 3 mariadb pods which are syncing data using galera, it is working fine as expected.
Now a other new k8s cluster is added in the network again having 3 mariadb pods and syncing data using galera.

What approach need to be followed to sync/replicate date across all 6 nodes from both cluster.

if someone can help with the approach and steps would be fine.

Design approach and steps to implement geo cluster data sync in mariadb

Comment: use [gmcast.segment](https://galeracluster.com/library/documentation/galera-parameters.html#gmcast-segment) and place all nodes on the same `wsrep_cluster_name` and with the cluster_address having all nodes.